# Question regarding powershell Compare-Object - issue capturing output to variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to store the results of a Compare-Object for later use.

When i store it in a variable, it comes up blank.

I reviewed the MSDN article on Compare-Object and it states no output is generated.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Without showing us your code we can only guess ...

Answer (score 4):

You can store the results of a comparsion like this:

```
$result = Compare-Object $object1 $object2
```

If you aren't getting anything put into **$result**, then the two objects are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$result = Compare-Object $a $b
```

$result will be empty when there is no difference. ( for example `$result = Compare-Object $a $a` ) . You can do something like `if($result)` to see if there is a difference and proceed accordingly.